# Segmentation Fault, debugging

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

My program code was working just a few hours ago, and I can seem to think what it is that I changed to give it a segmentation fault. I'm having a lot of trouble finding this pesky little error, if anyone could tell me the best way to debug something like this, that would be awesome.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


/*  VSIE client program uses TCP protocol to connect to the remote http server.
    The program will take 2 input arguments:
        1) command option, get (receive) or head (send)
        2) http URL address 
*/

#define MAX 80
#define MAX2 1024
#define http "HTTP/1.1"
#define TRUE   1
#define FALSE  0
#define HEADERSTOP "\n\n"
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    char *temp;
    unsigned char *e;
    char *line;
    char command[MAX];
    char server[MAX];
    char path[MAX];
    char filename[MAX]= "";
    char httpString[MAX];
    int i, x, f, n, length = 0;
    int numBytes = 0;
    int getData = TRUE;
    int getFlag = FALSE;
    int flag = FALSE;
    int headFlag = FALSE;
    FILE *in;

    int sk;
    unsigned char buf[MAX2];
    struct sockaddr_in remote;
    struct hostent *hp;
    struct servent *sp;
    short port = 0;


    // parse input arguments
    sscanf(argv[2],"%[^'/']%s",server,path);

    if (strcmp(argv[1],"-get") == 0)
    {
        sprintf(command, "GET");
        getFlag = TRUE;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[1],"-head") == 0)
    {
        sprintf(command, "HEAD");
    }

    //build http 1.1 GET or HEAD message
    sprintf(httpString,"%s %s %s\nHost: %s\n\n", command, path,http,server);

    printf("command = %s, server = %s, path = %s\n", command, server, path);
    printf("httpString = %s\n",httpString);

    //parse filename from path
    length = strlen(path);
    x=0;
    f=0;

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        //printf("path[%d] = %c \n",i,path[i]);
        if ((flag == TRUE) & (f == 2))
        {
            filename[x] = path[i];
            x++;
        }

        if (path[i] == '/')
        {
            flag = TRUE;
            f++;
        }

    }

    printf("filename = %s\n", filename);

    //if command = get, open filename   
    //if(command == "-get") 
    if (getFlag == TRUE)
    {
        if((in = fopen (filename,"w")) == NULL)
        {
            //printf("FAILURE: opening input file %s\n",filename);
            perror("FAILURE: opening input file");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("file opened successfully\n");
    }

    //get internet address of host & port number of http service
    hp = gethostbyname(server);
    if (hp == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Can't find host name. %s\n", server);
        exit (1);
    }

    //copy the h_addr (source) to s_add (destination) for n bytes specified by length
    bcopy(hp->h_addr,&remote.sin_addr.s_addr,hp->h_length);

    /* get the port     number */
    sp = getservbyname("http", "tcp");
    if (sp == NULL)
    {
        printf("can't find port # %d\n",sp->s_port);
        exit (1);
    }
    port = sp->s_port;
    remote.sin_port = sp->s_port;
    printf("port = %d, port = %d \n", port, remote.sin_port);

    //create socket for http server - socket type: Sock_Stream, protocol: TCP
    sk = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if (sk < 0)
    {
        perror("error opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    remote.sin_family = AF_INET;    

    //initiate connection to the server address w/ TCP socket
    if (connect(sk, (struct sockaddr *) &remote, sizeof(remote)) < 0) 
    {
        printf("connect fails!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("connection successful\n");

    //send http message
    printf("send message:%s\n", httpString);
    //send(sk,httpString,strlen(httpString)+1,0);
    if(send(sk,httpString,sizeof(httpString),0) < 0)
    {
        printf("send() failed");
        //exit(1);
    }

    n = 1;
    //Loop until all data received
    while(getData == TRUE)
    {   
        //wait for and print the return message
        numBytes = recv(sk,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
        if (numBytes < 0)
        {
            perror("error reading from socket");
            break;
        }
        else if (numBytes < MAX2)
        {
            getData = FALSE;
            printf("***end while loop****\n");
        }
        if (headFlag == FALSE){

            e = memchr(buf, '\n', sizeof(buf)); 

            while (*(e+1) != '\r'){
                e = memchr(e+1, '\n', sizeof(buf));
            }       
            sprintf(temp, "%s", e);
            headFlag = TRUE;
        }



        printf("\n****number of bytes received %d****\n",numBytes); 
        line = strtok(buf, "\n");
        while(line != NULL) {
            if (strstr(line, "Content-Length:")!= NULL){
                int dataSize;
                sscanf(line, "Content-Length: %d", &dataSize);
                printf("The Data Size: %d\n", dataSize);
            }
            line = strtok(NULL, "\n");


        //saved the retrieved content into the file (input argument)

        if (getFlag == TRUE)
        {
            //printf("write output\n");

            if(e != NULL){
                printf("%.*s\n", (int)(numBytes-sizeof(temp)), buf);
                fwrite(temp, sizeof(temp), 1, in);
                e = NULL;
            }else{
                fwrite(buf, numBytes, 1, in);
            }

        }
        n++;
    } // end while()

    //close socket & file
    close(sk);

    if(fclose(in) !=0)
    {
        perror("FAILURE: Closing input file");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
} //end main()
```

Comment: The best way to debug is to use a debugger

Comment: I've never actually used gdb, so I'm not quite sure what I'm doing with it.

Comment: Writing a hello world program without a debugger would be fine.  Not with this program.  If you want to make faster progress in getting code to work, I would invest in reading and learning how to use a debugger.  That will also help you to narrow the scope of any questions you need to post.

Comment: You have a lot of buffers declared with a size of `MAX`, which you've defined as `80`. You're then using those buffers for all sorts of things that could conceivably go beyond 80 characters, particularly `httpString`. Try increasing `MAX` to something you can be reasonably certain won't overflow, such as 4096. Then if it fixes your segfault, you'll have a better idea of where to look for what was causing it. If it doesn't fix your segfault, then at least you've eliminated one very frequently encountered cause of segfaults.

Comment: Also, learning to use `gdb` isn't difficult at all. Don't shy away from it because you think there's going to be some steep learning curve with it. There are also plenty of [GUI frontends](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/GDB%20Front%20Ends) for `gdb` if you'd rather not debug from the command line.

Comment: What @ryyker says.  If you cannot debug, you cannot develop software.  Note that 'debugging' does not mean 'post on SO so others get to do the really hard work'.  Writing code is easy. Designing data is harder.  Getting the whole lot to work correctly is hardest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is at

```
    sprintf(temp, "%s", e);
```

and

```
 if(fclose(in) !=0)
```

Verify the code at these two places.

After commenting these two parts, there is no segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Compile your code with the -g option.

Run gdb as - gdb /your executable/

from inside gdb just do - run /input arguments/

It should stop at the spot causing the segmentation fault. You should be able to do a stack trace by -where

Please refer - 
http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_284.html